# Map from the Grassmannian of the dual to the Grassmannian of the space - is it regular?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n$ over an algebraically closed field $F$. Let $0<d<n$.

Consider the map $f:G(d, V^*)\to G(n-d,V)$ between Grassmannians, given by $f(W)=\{v\in V\mid\lambda(v)=0 \,\,\,\forall\lambda\in W\}$ for every linear subspace $W$ of $V^*$ of dimension $d$.

> Is the map $f$ regular? (in the sense algebraic geometry)

I am used to thinking of a Grassmanian $G(m,E)$ as the Zariski closed subset of $\mathbb{P}(\Lambda^mE)$ consisting of the pure wedge products (and I am new to algebraic geometry).

Comment: Yes, this map is regular (and is an isomorphism).

Comment: @Sasha: Thank you, I suspected it is. But I don't see why!

Comment: There are many ways to see this. One is to note that you can extend this map to an isomoprhism of functors represented by the Grassmannians. Another --- to check that it is induced by a linear isomorphism $\Lambda^dV^* \cong \Lambda^{n-d}V$.

Comment: @Sasha: Thank you. I know how to write natural isomorphisms $\Lambda^{n-d}V\to (\Lambda^d V)^*$ (using a pairing) and $\Lambda^dV^*\to(\Lambda^d V)^*$ (using the determinant). I still don't see the entire picture.